# How to run a Firebase query inside an Object.keys loop based on the current item without causing an "await has to be inside an async function error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object loop, i am looping through each value, but I want to run a firebase query on every current item of the object loop but Firebase queries are asynchronous meaning i have to use an await prefix if i want to wait for the snapshot data, and i can only put an await inside an async function, so i keep getting the error that the await prefix for my firebase query snapshot has to be inside an async function, but the Object.keys is inside an async function but i guess it's not recognized as one, how can I still achieve what I want? to loop through each value and run a firebase query based on the current value, here is my attempt below which is causing an error

```
async function createTrades() {

        var docId;
        var snapshot;
        var snapshot2;


        Object.keys(betTrades).forEach((betPrice) => {

            var liability = parse.flost(betTrades[betPrice]['FOR']) * parse.float(betPrice);
            var ref = db.collection('trades');
            snapshot = await ref.where('marketOddsId', '==', betTrades[betPrice]['MARKETODDSID']).where('tradeMatchId', '==', betTrades[betPrice]['MATCHID']).where('price', '==', betPrice).get();


            var ref = db.collection('trades');
            snapshot2 = await ref.where('marketOddsId', '==', betTrades[betPrice]['MARKETODDSID']).where('tradeMatchId', '==', betTrades[betPrice]['MATCHID']).where('price', '==', betPrice).where('tradeStatus', '==', 'PARTIALLY_MATCHED').get();
```

Comment: You can make the method inside the foreach async ```Object.keys(betTrades).forEach(async(betPrice) => {});```

Comment: This code could be parallelised, however, it is unclear what you are doing with the snapshots once you have obtained them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a syntactic loop:

```js
for (let betPrice of Object.keys(betTrades)) {
  // your await-enabled code here
}
```

This way, you're still inside `async function createTrades`, and `await` works as expected.

Also note that using `async` in `forEach` *will not work*, because `forEach` doesn't know that it should `await` your async function that it iterates with.